# How to find the magnitude of a vector when I know the angle it travels from a point to a line?

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a point *P* and straight line *L* in 2D space. From point *P*, I can find the vector *V* reaching  perpendicular to the line *L*.
Suppose I rotated the vector *V* by *θ* about point *P*. Let's say this rotated vector is *V'*.
If we assume that this rotated vector *V'* can be extended to reach the line *L*, how do we find the magnitude of this vector?

[I want to know the magnitude of red vector in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80o7J.png)